# Can I restore master to a different name as a user database

Tags: restore, master

I need to look at the contents of sysdatabases from an older backup of master, but I do not want to overwrite my master databse.  Can I use the rename option of the restore command to restore master as something else ('MyDB')?

Comment: Please clarify, which Database Management System you use?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as you are restoring it to a server instance that is the same build number that it came from originally you should be fine.  If you try to restore a system database on an instance with different build number it will fail.